# Search in MongoDB with the condition to get only one result per attribute with the higehst version

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

Excuse my newbie question but I can't figure it out.
This is my collection:

```
[
  {
    _id: "A",
    uuid: "12345",
    version: 1,
    test: "data1"
  },
  {
    _id: "B",
    uuid: "56566",
    version: 1,
    test: "data2"
  },
  {
    _id: "C",
    uuid: "12345",
    version: 2,
    test: "data3"
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a query with a UuidContains condition and with a exact condition.

```
findByUuidContains(5)
-> Result: [B,C] as Object Array


findByUuidContains(12345)
-> Result: [C] as Object Array


findByUuidContains(66)
-> Result: [B]
```

Is this kind of query possible?
In words:
Select all Object that uuid contains ${value} and from the resultset select only one per uuid with the highest Version.

EDIT1:

I changed the group projection from answer:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$redact": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$gt": [
            {
              "$indexOfCP": [
                {
                  "$toLower": "$uuid"
                },
                "5"
              ]
            },
            -1
          ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      version: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        uuid: "$uuid"
      },
      version: {
        $first: "$version"
      },
      id: {
        $first: "$_id"
      },
      test: {
        $first: "$test"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      num: "1",
      id: 1,
      _id: 0,
      version: 1,
      test: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$num",
      "result": {
        "$addToSet": {
          id: "$id",
          version: "$version",
          test: "$test"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      result: 1
    }
  }
])
```

and I added some test data attributes to my documents. Now I have to 'translate' it into the spring boot 'language'

EDIT2:

I'm currently trying to translate the second answer but I can't figure out how the GroupOpertaion in Spring works. Somebody familiar with it? The first and second operation works like the mongo query operations but it failed by the group operation

```
        String uuidRegexExp = String.format(".*%s.*", uuidSegment);
        Pattern uuidPattern = Pattern.compile(uuidRegexExp);
        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("uuid").regex(uuidPattern));

        SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"version");
        GroupOperation grup = Aggregation.group("version").first("version").as("version"); 
        Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                match, sort, grup
        );

        AggregationResults<Example> aggregate1 = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, Example.COLLECTION_NAME, Example.class);

        aggregate1.getMappedResults().forEach(er -> log.info(er.toString()));
```

This is the example class:

```
@Data
@Document(Example.COLLECTION_NAME)
public class Example {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "Example";
    public static final String FIELD_UUID_NAME = "uuid";
    public static final String FIELD_HOST_NAME = "host";
    public static final String FIELD_URL_NAME = "url";
    public static final String FIELD_VERSION_NAME = "version";
    public static final String FIELD_ID_NAME = "_id";


    @Field(FIELD_ID_NAME)
    private ObjectId _id;

    @Field(FIELD_UUID_NAME)
    private String uuid;

    @Field(FIELD_HOST_NAME)
    private String host;

    @Field(FIELD_URL_NAME)
    private String url;

    @Field(FIELD_VERSION_NAME)
    private Long version;
}
```

EDIT3:

I think I have done it. Here is the Code in a not pretty version:

```
        String uuidRegexExp = String.format(".*%s.*", uuidSegment);
        Pattern uuidPattern = Pattern.compile(uuidRegexExp);
        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("uuid").regex(uuidPattern));

        SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"version");
        GroupOperation grup = Aggregation.group("uuid").first("version").as("version").first("_id").as("id");
        ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project().and("_id").as("uuid").and("version").as("version").and("id").as("_id");
        
        Aggregation aggregate = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                match, sort, grup,project
        );


        AggregationResults<Example> aggregate1 = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregate, SingleRawArticle.COLLECTION_NAME, Example.class);
```

Comment: As per your problem, findByUuidContains(5)
-> Result: [B,C] as Object Array should give the output as [A,B,C], because A also contains 5. Right?

Comment: And you UUID field is string or double?

Comment: Yes this is the problem. The result is [A,B,C] (because my query is wrong) but it should be [B,C]. UUID is a string

Comment: I have added a shorter script. Do check if that helps you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for? I have created mongo playground for it. You can check the query by passing diffrent parameters. I have used `5` in example like below. But i have also tried with `12345` and `66` and it looks fine to me.

```js
{
              "$indexOfCP": [
                {
                  "$toLower": "$uuid"
                },
                "5"
              ]
            },
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rKH_8qFxKzD)

Here is the query :

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$redact": {
      "$cond": [
        {
          "$gt": [
            {
              "$indexOfCP": [
                {
                  "$toLower": "$uuid"
                },
                "5"
              ]
            },
            -1
          ]
        },
        "$$KEEP",
        "$$PRUNE"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      version: -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        uuid: "$uuid"
      },
      version: {
        $first: "$version"
      },
      id: {
        $first: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      num: "1",
      id: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$num",
      "result": {
        "$addToSet": "$id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0,
      result: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Yes! This is not exactly what I'm looking for, because I need the hole document B and C and not only the _id. I wasn't clear in my post at the first place. This is a great job thanks I'll try and error to the hole document solution in your playground.

Answer (score 2):

check the below query to get the documents matching the given string. I have used regex to match the input string.

```
    db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : { 
                "uuid" : { 
                    "$regex" : ".*5.*"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : { 
                "version" : -1.0
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : { 
                "_id" : { 
                    "uuid" : "$uuid"
                }, 
                "uuid" : { 
                    "$first" : "$uuid"
                }, 
                "id" : { 
                    "$first" : "$_id"
                }, 
                "version" : { 
                    "$first" : "$version"
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : { 
                "_id" : "$id", 
                "uuid" : 1.0, 
                "version" : 1.0
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

Output:

```
   { 
    "uuid" : "12345", 
    "version" : 2.0, 
    "_id" : "C"
}
{ 
    "uuid" : "56566", 
    "version" : 1.0, 
    "_id" : "B"
}
```

Comment: Your solution maps the _id to the uuid. Is there any reason why?

Comment: but then you have to project like the first answer to get the origin format or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you need to add a project stage. I have modified the earlier query. Do have a look. Modified the query to get UUID from group stage and then project it in original format

Answer (score 0):

Java code equivalent to query. Modified your edit according to the latest changes. Changed variable names to be more specific.

```
String uuidRegexExp = String.format(".*%s.*", uuidSegment);
        MatchOperation match = new MatchOperation(Criteria.where("uuid").regex(Pattern.compile(uuidRegexExp)));

        SortOperation sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"version");
        GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("uuid").first("version").as("version").first("_id").as("id").first("uuid").as("uuid");
        ProjectionOperation project = Aggregation.project().and("uuid").as("uuid").and("version").as("version").and("id").as("_id");
        
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                match, sort, group,project
        );


        AggregationResults<Example> aggregate = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, SingleRawArticle.COLLECTION_NAME, Example.class);
```